# Как исправить кодировку вывода minGW в окне вывода в NetBeans?

Tags: c++, netbeans, mingw

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Win7 в обычной cmd.exe вывод корректный, пробовал менять кодировку проекта (правый клик по проекту --> свойства), менять шрифты у этого окна (правый клик мыши по окну --> настройки) - безрезультатно.

Comment: Нашёл ещё одно место где выбирается кодировка, в общих настройках NetBeans в разделе C/C++, стояла 1252 вместо 1251...